# Mulesoft - cloudhub runtime update issues - HTTP connector

Tags: http, runtime, grizzly, mulesoft, cloudhub

I am updating the runtime version of an application in cloudhub(anypoint platform - mulesoft).

In detail, updated the runtime 3.9.0 -2018 release to runtime 3.9.0 - 2019 latest version. I am able to successfully deploy the application and it is started without any issues.

Later, When I am trying to make HTTP request to application. It errors out as below ::

```
ERROR
********************************************************************************
Message: org.glassfish.grizzly.connectionpool.Endpoint.connect(Lorg/glassfish/grizzly/CompletionHandler;)Lorg/glassfish/grizzly/GrizzlyFuture; (java.lang.AbstractMethodError).
Element: /get:\/redacted:redacted-config/processors/0 @ redacted:redacted.xml:44 (HTTP)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
org.glassfish.grizzly.connectionpool.Endpoint.connect(Lorg/glassfish/grizzly/CompletionHandler;)Lorg/glassfish/grizzly/GrizzlyFuture; (java.lang.AbstractMethodError). (org.mule.api.MessagingException)
  org.glassfish.grizzly.connectionpool.SingleEndpointPool.connect(SingleEndpointPool.java:1158)
  org.glassfish.grizzly.connectionpool.SingleEndpointPool.take(SingleEndpointPool.java:790)
  org.glassfish.grizzly.connectionpool.MultiEndpointPool.take(MultiEndpointPool.java:592)
  com.ning.http.client.providers.grizzly.ConnectionManager.openAsync(ConnectionManager.java:143)
  com.ning.http.client.providers.grizzly.GrizzlyAsyncHttpProvider.execute(GrizzlyAsyncHttpProvider.java:174)
  com.ning.http.client.AsyncHttpClient.executeRequest(AsyncHttpClient.java:505)
  com.ning.http.client.AsyncHttpClient.executeRequest(AsyncHttpClient.java:527)
  org.mule.module.http.internal.request.grizzly.GrizzlyHttpClient.sendAndWait(GrizzlyHttpClient.java:360)
  org.mule.module.http.internal.request.grizzly.GrizzlyHttpClient.send(GrizzlyHttpClient.java:307)
  com.mulesoft.mule.http.request.grizzly.EEGrizzlyHttpClient.send(EEGrizzlyHttpClient.java:105)
  (191 more...)

  (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************
```

Comment: Please add a more complete error description from the log. That looks like a single line from the stacktrace part. Please copy the complete error description plus the stacktrace.

Comment: I added the relevant bit from our logs here, presuming SumanthMohan has a similar one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating Mule 3.9.0 in CloudHub to the October 24 2019 release should resolve that issue.

Having said that, I usually recommend to also upgrade to the last version, 3.9.3, which includes many other fixes.

Comment: I am able to get response without errors after updating the patch.

 

Mulesoft released the patch on October 24, 2019

3.9.0 and 3.9.1 Runtime Update:

Bug fixes and improvements [SE-13669]